# How to close System dialogs that appears on app crash?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I'm using xcuitest framework to automate mac application. I get system dialogs when the app is opened again after it crashes. I want to handle the dialog programmatically. But the dialog appears under the process `UserNotificationCenter' instead of the application under test. How can I handle the alert in such case?

Comment: Do you try to use `InterruptionMonitor` for this?

Comment: Yes. InterruptionMonitor seems to work but it somehow makes the test to run a longer time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use `InterruptionMonitor` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496273-adduiinterruptionmonitor), [use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803842/xcuitesting-for-permission-popup-alert-appears-but-uiinterruptionmonitor-does)). This
   approach is however kinda old and I found, that it does not work for
   all dialogs and situations.
2. Create a method, which will wait for some regular app's button. If the app's button (or tab bar or other such XCUIElement) is visible and hittable after your app started, you can proceed with your test and if it's not, you can wait for the `UserNotificationCenter` dialog's button and identify&tap it by its string/position.

I'm using the second approach and its working much better, than the `InterruptionMonitor`. But it really depends on your app layout and use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to revent it from appearing in the first place.  Something like:

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none
```